Задача о супермаркете с использованием семафора на C
Всем привет! Такая задача "Ввести мьютексы, семафоры или блокировки чтения-записи для защиты критических секций. Если в задании указан конкретный механизм для защиты, использовать только его. Задача о супермаркете. В супермаркете работают два кассира, покупатели заходят в супермаркет, делают покупки и становятся в очередь к случайному кассиру. Пока очередь пуста, кассир спит, как только появляется покупатель, кассир просыпается. Покупатель спит в очереди, пока не подойдет к кассиру. Создать многопоточное приложение, моделирующее рабочий день супермаркета."
Вот что я накалякал (не кидайте тапками за говнокод, я не знаком с Си вообще, это ужас, что нам эту методичку дали). В программе работает только функция покупателя, а кассиры бесконечно каждую секунду обслуживают покупателя 0. Я не понимаю почему, как будто семафоры не работают, но вроде все делаю правильно (по крайней мере как я понял работу семафоров)
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_CUSTOMERS 10
#define NUM_CASHIERS 2

typedef struct {
    int customers[NUM_CUSTOMERS];
    int front;
    int rear;
} Queue;

Queue queue[NUM_CASHIERS];

pthread_mutex_t mutex_cashiers[NUM_CASHIERS]; // Мьютексы для кассиров
sem_t sem_cashiers[NUM_CASHIERS];

void initializeQueue(Queue *queue) {
    queue->front = 0;
    queue->rear = 0;
}

void enqueue(Queue *queue, int item) {
    queue->customers[queue->rear] = item;
    queue->rear = (queue->rear + 1) % NUM_CUSTOMERS;
}

int dequeue(Queue *queue) {
    int item = queue->customers[queue->front];
    queue->front = (queue->front + 1) % NUM_CUSTOMERS;
    return item;
}

void *cashier(void *args) {
    int cashier_number = *((int *)args);

    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&sem_cashiers[cashier_number]);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_cashiers[cashier_number]);

        int customer_num = dequeue(&queue[cashier_number]);
        printf("Касса %d обслуживает покупателя %d.\n", cashier_number + 1, customer_num);
        sleep(1);
        printf("Касса %d завершила обслуживание покупателя %d.\n", cashier_number + 1, customer_num);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_cashiers[cashier_number]);
    }
}

void *customer(void *args) {
    int customer_number = *((int *)args);
    sleep(rand() % 10 + 1);
    printf("Покупатель %d зашёл в магазин и делает покупки...\n", customer_number);
    sleep(rand() % 10 + 1);
    int cashier_choice = rand() % NUM_CASHIERS;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_cashiers[cashier_choice]);

    enqueue(&queue[cashier_choice], customer_number);
    printf("Покупатель %d встал в очередь к Кассе %d.\n", customer_number, cashier_choice + 1);

    sem_post(&sem_cashiers[cashier_choice]);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_cashiers[cashier_choice]);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t threads_cashiers[NUM_CASHIERS];
    pthread_t threads_customers[NUM_CUSTOMERS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CASHIERS; i++) {
        int *cashier_number = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *cashier_number = i;
        pthread_create(&threads_cashiers[i], NULL, cashier, (void *)cashier_number);

        initializeQueue(&queue[i]);
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_cashiers[i], NULL);
        sem_init(&sem_cashiers[i], 0, 0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CUSTOMERS; i++) {
        int *customer_number = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *customer_number = i;
        pthread_create(&threads_customers[i], NULL, customer, (void *)customer_number);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CUSTOMERS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads_customers[i], NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CASHIERS; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_cashiers[i]);
        sem_destroy(&sem_cashiers[i]);
        pthread_join(threads_cashiers[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}


неправильный порядок. Поток ждёт не инициализированный семафор и замок. Сначала у вас выполняется sem_wait(&sem_cashiers[cashier_number]);pthread_mutex_lock.. а потом вы только выполняете sem_init(&sem_cashiers[i], 0, 0);. Поменяйте порядок вызовов sem_init  pthread_mutex_init pthread_create

хм, да, спасибо. Поменял, однако проблема осталась

В общем, проблема в том, что я сижу на MacOS. По своей тупости не обращал внимания на предупреждение sem_t is derpicated. Сегодня со свежей головой начал опять думать над заданием и сразу обратил внимание на предупреждение, загуглил. Вот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736618/why-are-sem-init-sem-getvalue-sem-destroy-deprecated-on-mac-os-x-and-w
